# Add a Rand to each row using Pandas' Assign and a Lambda Function

Tags: python, pandas, random, lambda, assign

How do I pass a random number to a lambda function, so that I can be used by the pandas `assign` to add a different random number to each row.

My original attempt,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': [1]*10 + [0]*10,
                   'value': [3]*5 + [2]*5 + [2]*2 + [3]*8})

df.assign(cat=lambda df: df.cat + np.random.rand(1)).head(3)

Out[1]:
     cat        value
0   1.962857    3
1   1.962857    3
2   1.962857    3
```

We see here that the the random number `0.962857` has been added to all rows. But I would like a different `rand` for each row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `1`, because return scalar to array by `length` of `DataFrame`:

```
print (np.random.rand(1))
[ 0.88642869]

print (np.random.rand(len(df)))

[ 0.42677701  0.89968857  0.87976326  0.07758206  0.43617027  0.03221375
  0.46398119  0.14226246  0.14237448  0.22679517  0.60271752  0.85003435
  0.5676184   0.87565266  0.89830548  0.27066452  0.23907483  0.73784657
  0.09083235  0.98984701]
```

---

```
df = df.assign(cat=lambda df: df.cat + np.random.rand(len(df))).head(3)
print (df)
        cat  value
0  1.886429      3
1  1.426777      3
2  1.899689      3
```

Comment: Odd - I tried `df = df.assign(cat=lambda df: df.cat + np.random.rand(df.shape[0], 1)).head(3)` and got the following error: `Wrong number of items passed ... placement imples 1` and this threw me off. Thanks.

Comment: You need `df = df.assign(cat=lambda df: df.cat + np.random.rand(df.shape[0])).head(3)`

Comment: I see that `df.shape[0]` is just slightly less terse than `len(df)` but why does pandas handle a n-length 1D `np.array` so different to an nx1, 2D array? I think that was the crux of my problem.

Comment: I think you need change it to `df = df.assign(cat=lambda df: df[['cat']] + np.random.rand(df.shape[0], 1)).head(3)` - `df[['cat']]` return one column `DataFrame`

Comment: What if I have to do it in more columns? @jezrael

Comment: @DimKoim - Can youexplain more?

Comment: Assume that you have an extra colum `'cat_new': [2]*10 + [1.3]*10}`. If you want to  iterate you will do: `for column in [cat, cat_new]: df[column] = df[column].assign(column=lambda df: df[column] + np.random.rand(len(df))).head(3)` then you have an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'assign'
`

Comment: I figure out how to do it but I am asking that out of curiosity :)

Comment: @DimKoim - Use `cols = ['cat', 'cat_new']
df[cols] = df[cols] + np.random.rand(len(df), len(cols))`